# Redirect entire website (Wordpress) links to another website except 3 links via htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect entire website (Wordpress) links on a subdomain to another website except 3 links via htaccess. I tried different rules but its not working as the whole. I need to exclude below links from the redirection i.e
-- the homepage of the other website /
-- /link1
-- /link2

I tried the below

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/malta
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/manila
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Please help.